# Godot player not walking in the direction

Tags: godot

So I am new to godot and I was having a problem. The players body doesnt follow the camera when the camera moves When I look around with the camera the players body stays the same e.g. if i use wasd if i turn to the right it would be aswd. the player movement is hard but i got help. if you could help that will be super cool, i am just trying to learn coding. this is hard for me.

p.s sorry for the bad grammar

```
extends KinematicBody

signal hit

# How fast the player moves in meters per second.
export var speed = 14
# The downward acceleration when in the air, in meters per second squared.
export var fall_acceleration = 50
# Vertical impulse applied to the character upon jumping in meters per second.
export var jump_impulse = 30
# Vertical impulse applied to the character upon bouncing over a mob in meters per second.
export var bounce_impulse = 16

# stats
var curHP : int = 10
var maxHP : int = 10
var ammo : int = 15
var score : int = 0


# cam look
var minLookAngle : float = -90.0
var maxLookAngle : float = 90.0
var lookSensitivity : float = 10.0

# vectors
var vel : Vector3 = Vector3()
var mouseDelta : Vector2 = Vector2()

# components
onready var camera : Camera = get_node("Camera")
onready var muzzle : Spatial = get_node("Camera/Muzzle")


# Emitted when a mob hit the player.


var velocity = Vector3.ZERO


func _physics_process(delta):
var direction = Vector3.ZERO

if Input.is_action_pressed("move_right"):
    direction.x += 1
if Input.is_action_pressed("move_left"):
    direction.x -= 1
if Input.is_action_pressed("move_back"):
    direction.z += 1
if Input.is_action_pressed("move_forward"):
    direction.z -= 1
    
#sprinting
if Input.is_action_pressed("move_sprint"):
    speed = 50
if Input.is_action_just_released("move_sprint"):
    speed = 14



velocity.x = direction.x * speed
velocity.z = direction.z * speed

# Jumping.
if is_on_floor() and Input.is_action_just_pressed("move_jump"):
    velocity.y += jump_impulse

velocity.y -= fall_acceleration * delta
velocity = move_and_slide(velocity, Vector3.UP)



func _ready():

# hide and lock the mouse cursor
Input.set_mouse_mode(Input.MOUSE_MODE_CAPTURED) 


    
func _process(delta):

# rotate the camera along the x axis
camera.rotation_degrees.x -= mouseDelta.y * lookSensitivity * delta

# clamp camera x rotation axis
camera.rotation_degrees.x = clamp(camera.rotation_degrees.x, minLookAngle, maxLookAngle)

# rotate the player along their y-axis
rotation_degrees.y -= mouseDelta.x * lookSensitivity * delta

# reset the mouseDelta vector
mouseDelta = Vector2()

func _input(event):

if event is InputEventMouseMotion:
    mouseDelta = event.relative
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want the movement to be based on the orientation of camera...

Then base the movement:

```
var direction = Vector3.ZERO

if Input.is_action_pressed("move_right"):
    direction.x += 1
if Input.is_action_pressed("move_left"):
    direction.x -= 1
if Input.is_action_pressed("move_back"):
    direction.z += 1
if Input.is_action_pressed("move_forward"):
    direction.z -= 1
```

On the orientation of the `camera`.

We will use `camera.global_transform.basis`. The `basis` of a `transform` gives us a set of vectors that are aligned to the axis of the transformed space.

*Using `camera.transform` instead of `camera.global_transform` will NOT work, because the `Camera` is a child of the `KinematicBody`.*

Then your code ends up like this:

```
var direction = Vector3.ZERO
var camera_x = camera.global_transform.basis.x
var camera_z = camera.global_transform.basis.z

if Input.is_action_pressed("move_right"):
    direction += camera_x
if Input.is_action_pressed("move_left"):
    direction -= camera_x
if Input.is_action_pressed("move_back"):
    direction += camera_z
if Input.is_action_pressed("move_forward"):
    direction -= camera_z
```

---

Complete script on OP request:

```
extends KinematicBody

#signal hit

# How fast the player moves in meters per second.
export var speed = 14
# The downward acceleration when in the air, in meters per second squared.
export var fall_acceleration = 50
# Vertical impulse applied to the character upon jumping in meters per second.
export var jump_impulse = 30
# Vertical impulse applied to the character upon bouncing over a mob in meters per second.
# export var bounce_impulse = 16

# stats
# var curHP : int = 10
# var maxHP : int = 10
# var ammo : int = 15
# var score : int = 0


# cam look
var minLookAngle : float = -90.0
var maxLookAngle : float = 90.0
var lookSensitivity : float = 10.0

# vectors
# var vel : Vector3 = Vector3()
var mouseDelta : Vector2 = Vector2()

# components
onready var camera : Camera = get_node("Camera")
# onready var muzzle : Spatial = get_node("Camera/Muzzle")


# Emitted when a mob hit the player.


var velocity = Vector3.ZERO


func _physics_process(delta):
    var direction = Vector3.ZERO
    var camera_x = camera.global_transform.basis.x
    var camera_z = camera.global_transform.basis.z

    if Input.is_action_pressed("move_right"):
        direction += camera_x
    if Input.is_action_pressed("move_left"):
        direction -= camera_x
    if Input.is_action_pressed("move_back"):
        direction += camera_z
    if Input.is_action_pressed("move_forward"):
        direction -= camera_z
        
    #sprinting
    if Input.is_action_pressed("move_sprint"):
        speed = 50
    if Input.is_action_just_released("move_sprint"):
        speed = 14



    velocity.x = direction.x * speed
    velocity.z = direction.z * speed

    # Jumping.
    if is_on_floor() and Input.is_action_just_pressed("move_jump"):
        velocity.y += jump_impulse

    velocity.y -= fall_acceleration * delta
    velocity = move_and_slide(velocity, Vector3.UP)



func _ready():

    # hide and lock the mouse cursor
    Input.set_mouse_mode(Input.MOUSE_MODE_CAPTURED) 


    
func _process(delta):

    # rotate the camera along the x axis
    camera.rotation_degrees.x -= mouseDelta.y * lookSensitivity * delta

    # clamp camera x rotation axis
    camera.rotation_degrees.x = clamp(camera.rotation_degrees.x, minLookAngle, maxLookAngle)

    # rotate the player along their y-axis
    rotation_degrees.y -= mouseDelta.x * lookSensitivity * delta

    # reset the mouseDelta vector
    mouseDelta = Vector2()

func _input(event):

    if event is InputEventMouseMotion:
        mouseDelta = event.relative
```

Comment: i tried adding it but it gave me errors would you be able to put it together

Comment: @johnlohmann It worked for me, with your code, just replacing that part of the code. I had the `Camera` as child of the `KinematicBody`, and added the input mappings your code used. I had to fix some indentations (edit: is that the error?). I also removed parts of the code were not used because they gave me warnings (edit: not necessary for this to work). What errors did you get?

Comment: error Unexpected token if: p.s. thanks for helping me

Comment: @johnlohmann That has happened to me with some copied code. It is probably the new lines. Where the error shows up, try removing the new line (so what was two lines is a single line) and insert the new line again.

Comment: sorry to massage you but it still wont work could you put it together??? if not thats ok

Comment: @johnlohmann I added the whole script as I have it in Godot. However, honestly, I do not see why copying this would work when copying the smaller code didn't. I remind you that you can type the code yourself.

Comment: omg thank you. you saved my life. i tryed it but it gave me func errors.